# Django autocomplete_light and cities_light - invalid choice

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I have a model with a location field that is mapped to cities_light.city and I'm using an autocomplete field that allows users to type in their city and have it autocompleted to the correct/valid location model instance.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(City, blank=True, null=True)

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('location')
        widgets = {
            'location': autocomplete_light.TextWidget(CityAutocomplete, autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder':'City, Country', 'minimum_characters':4})
        }
```

The form field works exactly as advertised and a list of autocomplete options are shown. However when I save the form/model I get a validation error which seems to be caused by the field not being translated into the primary key of the City model instance.

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

I'm guessing I need to extend the AutocompleteModelBase like the CityAutocomplete implemented below but I'm not sure how and I've been unable to find a working example.

```
class CityAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ('search_names',)
```

https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light/blob/master/cities_light/contrib/autocompletes.py

Thank for any assistance and I'm sorry if my question is poorly formatted.

Comment: `fields = ('location')` should be `fields = ('location',)` or `fields = ['location']`. To check if the field was being translated correctly, inspect the hidden select element. Also, is there any way you can reproduce the bug in the test_project ?

Comment: I don't see any hidden select element. I'm using the autocomplete.TextWidget not a select field. But I do see that the actual value I want is the data-value of the autocomplete elements. The string name of the city is sent instead of the id. fields change made no difference. I'll have a look at the test_project, thank you.

Comment: Oh I'm also using django 1.5 which I forgot to mention.

Comment: BTW I also tested using the simplified examples in test_project and it works fine with the option select widget, but there are thousands of cities which is why I wanted to use the text field instead. Any help is appreciated, I'm still looking around the test_project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not specific to django-autocomplete-light. What you're doing has no chance to work and here's why:

- the form field for a `ForeignKey` like `location` is a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) by default,
- `ModelChoiceField` accepts values which are pks of models in `ModelChoiceField.queryset`, which is `TheModel.objects.all()` by default,
- the `TextWidget` widget [is a `TextInput`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/autocomplete_light/widgets.html#TextWidget),
- a [`TextInput` widget is just an `<input type="text" />`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#textinput),
- the value of a `<input type="text" />` is directly sent to the server on form submission.

As a result, selecting a couple of cities like "Lisboa" and "Madrid" with a text widget will look like::

```
<input type="text" value="Lisboa, Madrid" name="location" />
```

Which means that the form will post `{'location': 'Lisboa, Madrid'}`. While this is good for a `CharField`, it won't work for a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` which would expect something like `{'location': [3,5]}` where 3 would be the pk of Lisboa and 5 the pk of Madrid.

In the same fashion, a `ModelChoiceField` would expect `{'location': 3}` which `autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget` is able to do.

To fix this, use a `ChoiceWidget` instead of a `TextWidget`. I have clarified this [in the tutorial](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-autocomplete-widgets-in-non-model-forms) I hope it is better now.

Comment: You are correct. After looking through your examples in the test_project I changed my implementation slightly to reflect that of the generic_inline app because I want people to be able to type in a location. This also means users can now generalize their location (ie. country or region instead of city) if they want more privacy. It may also be worth noting that the field did not display the preset location until I changed from ModelForm to autocomplete_light.GenericModelForm. Maybe I will submit an example app for your test_project. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Nice job ! Generic foreign keys are rather an advanced topic ;)

Comment: Yes, and I'm very new to python and django as well. The only thing I've noticed is that there are two spans with the close icons when displaying a form that has a set location.

Comment: I don't understand ... does this look like a bug ? Is it reproducible in the test_project ?

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or something I've done. When I add the value initially the text field is replaced with the location and remove span. But when I revisit the form a second time there are two remove spans. It's not reproducible in the inlines_outside_admin which is slightly different.

Comment: It seems to be related to the javascript for widgets, like its being executed twice. I'm just double checking im not loading jquery twice, and I might try disabling compression on js files.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me how to reproduce the issue so that I could see by myself and if it's a bug i'll fix it else i'll tell you what the problem is ;)

Comment: The problem is apparently caused by wysihtml5.js, I'll find another lib for that. Thank you for your help, I'll follow your repo on github.